# Common init-parameters in web.xml for multiple java servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, init-parameters

My current understanding is that init-params in the web.xml must be put in the body of a servlet variable, like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <description>debug</description> 
        <param-name>debug</param-name> 
        <param-value>true</param-value> 
    </init-param>   
</servlet>
```

Which works fine, but if I bring the init-param outside the servlet body, then it no longer recognizes it when I call getInitParam()

Just wondering if it was possible, since I have 3 servlets that I would like to share common init parameters

Answer (score 11):

No, you cannot achieve that using servlet init-param. If you want common init-param across servlets you should use Context Parameters.

**This is how you can do that:**

```
<context-param>
    <description>debug</description> 
    <param-name>debug</param-name> 
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And, use [ServletContext.getInitParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) within the servlet.